# Given a campgrounds array, return the total number of campsites in the array

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone could someone help me please to see if I am missing anything. Looks like I can't convert them to numbers.

```js
//This is the data I have:

let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

//This is my code so far.

function campsiteCount(campgrounds) {
  let counter = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    counter = counter + campgrounds[i];
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Each time your loop runs `campgrounds[i]` will be one of your objects in your array. Since you want to add the number in that object to the `counter` value, you need to grab that `number` property from the object using: `campgrounds[i].number`

Comment: I think it supposed to be 5 campgrounds not the value of number:xx. I think I supposed to get an answer: 5. Insted I get 59(values of 5 campsite numbers).

Comment: @wekilow if you mean 5 campgrounds then you can simply do: var total = campgrounds.length;  You don't need the for loop in that case.

Comment: @ HenryDev let me try UPD: Undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally just want the number of campgrounds in the campgrounds array, you can just use:

```
campgrounds.length
```

Like you already have in the for loop

If for whatever reason you need to increment the count in the for loop (maybe this is some sort of assignment given to you for learning purposes, still seems a bit odd as you used campgrounds.length in the for loop initialiser), you can just increment the count on every iteration:

```
function campsiteCount(campgrounds) {
  let counter = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    counter++;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to sum up all of the party sizes, which I assume is probably what you wanted? You would do it like this:

```
function campsiteCount(campgrounds) {
  let counter = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    counter += campgrounds[i].partySize;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(campgrounds.length);
```

Arrays have a `.length` property that will tell you the number of items in the array (which you're already using in your for loop).

Answer (score -1):

```js
//For future reference, this worked:

function campsiteCount(campgrounds) {
  let counter = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    counter = campgrounds.length;
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, you actually really don't need this function at all. Whenever you need the number of campgrounds, you can literally just use `campgrounds.length`. This might not have been too clear from my answer.

I.e, 

`let campsiteCount = campgrounds.length` - Should do what you want

Or if you really need this to be in a function:

`function campsiteCount(campgrounds) {
  return campgrounds.length;
}`

Will also do the trick